# How to specify a dependency for hexo

Tags: css, npm, gulp, hexo

I am trying to migrate my jekyll theme to `hexo`. In that theme I use `gulp` and a series of dependencies, for example `kouto-swiss`. Now, I've created a bare-bone blog in `hexo` and place my jekyll css files in the css folder for the `hexo` theme.

When I try to build the site using the theme I get the error:

```
Error: /home/hkr/Desarrollo/blog/themes/cards/source/css/main.styl:21:9
   21| @import "kouto-swiss"
---------------^
```

I've tried to add `"kouto-swiss"` as a dependency of the `hexo` blog, like this:

```
{
  "name": "hexo-site",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "hexo": {
    "version": "3.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "hexo": "^3.2.0",
    "hexo-generator-archive": "^0.1.4",
    "hexo-generator-category": "^0.1.3",
    "hexo-generator-index": "^0.2.0",
    "hexo-generator-tag": "^0.2.0",
    "hexo-renderer-ejs": "^0.2.0",
    "hexo-renderer-marked": "^0.2.10",
    "hexo-renderer-stylus": "^0.3.1",
    "hexo-server": "^0.2.0",
    "kouto-swiss": "^1.0.0" <<-- Tried as dependency
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-htmlclean": "^2.7.8",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "hexo": "^3.2.2",
    "kouto-swiss": "^1.0.0", <<-- And a dev dependency
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2"
  }
}
```

But I can't get `hexo clean && hexo generate` to work, I keep getting: `failed to locate @import file kouto-swiss.styl`

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Regards

**NOTE**

I can resolve this error writting:

`@import "../../../../node_modules/kouto-swiss"`

But I do not think this is the correct way of doing it. Is there a way of simply writing `@import "kouto-swiss"`?

Comment: What kind of dependency are you trying to import...? If you can solve using `node_modules` path, maybe installing `kouto-swiss` as global package (using `npm install -g kouto-swiss`)

Comment: @JuanjoSalvador `kouto-swiss`

Comment: When installing a client-side dependency (e.g. a css file) with node you usually need the full path to get that files, unless you import them using a require (for example, in gulp) assuming the package is ready for gulp. Making it global doesn't seem a good option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access npm-installed package in hexo app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755626/how-to-access-npm-installed-package-in-hexo-app)